# Modeling - symmetrizing part of a mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am currently working on the column.  When I smooth shaded it to see how smooth it is I noticed that the ring base of the column is not perfectly smooth because the to sphere modifier I used to make the square base round mess this part of the mesh a bit.

[image]

[image]

**Is there a fast way to make blende smooth or symmetrize the part of the mesh highlighted in the photo?**

I tried to do it but retouching single vertices but it will never be perfectly smooth.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can correct this shape manually, using two tools.

**01) Scale tool**
- correct the height of edge rings, so they're level.
- just scale them to 0 along the Z axis

[image]

**02) To Sphere Tool**
- this tool will make a circle from any shape
- you can use it to correct the roundness of your edge rings
- select the edge ring and go *Mesh > To Sphere* (click anywhere to activate it)

[image]